# React Native images and sound not playing on real device

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, chat, react-native-ios

I have a chat screen, from which I display sent/received texts, images and voice notes, the every thing is working pretty well in the simulator but in the real device texts are displayed but images and voice notes bubbles are just a blank space.

[image]

Here is my simulator, but on a real device all I see is a blank space with the height and width of the content that should be displayed.

Here is my chat.js file

```
<Container loading={ this.state.loading }>

    <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />

      <View style={ styles.messages_outer_container }>

        <View style={ styles.countdown_container }>

          <Text style={ styles.countdown }> { (this.state.appointment.status == 'completed') ? 'Appointment Completed' : this.state.session ? this.state.session : 'Waiting For Consultant Approval' } </Text>

          <View style={ styles.countdown_hr } />

        </View>

        <FlatList
          inverted
          ref={ (ref) => this.chat_list = ref }
          data={ this.state.on_load_message }
          keyExtractor={ item => item.id }
          renderItem={ ({ item }) => <ChatBubbles message={ item } from={ this.state.from } /> }
        />

      </View>

      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">

        <ChatBottomContainer
          set_message={ (message) => this.setState({ message }) }
          send_message={ () => this.send_message(this.state.message, 'text') }
          message={ this.state.message }
          end_session={ this.state.end_session }
          send_attachment={ this.send_attachment }
          send_voice_note={ this.send_voice_note }
        />

      </KeyboardAvoidingView>

    </Container>
```

Here is my chat-bubbles.js

```
class ChatBubbles extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { timer: moment().minute(0).second(0), is_playing: false };
  }

  play_sound = (file_path) => {

let voice_note = new Sound(file_path, undefined, error => {

  if (error) {
    console.warn(error);
    return;
  }

  else {

    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.setState(prev => ({ timer: prev.timer.add(1, 'second') })), 1000)

    this.setState({ is_playing: true })

    voice_note.play(() => {

      voice_note.release()

      clearInterval(this.timer)

      this.setState({ timer: moment().minute(0).second(0) })

      this.setState({ is_playing: false })

    })

  }

    })

  }

  render () {

    return (

      <View style={ styles.container }>

        <View style={ [ styles.message_bubble_container, (this.props.message.sender == this.props.from) ? { justifyContent: 'flex-start' } : { justifyContent: 'flex-end' } ] }>

            {
              (this.props.message.type == 'image')

          ? <View style={ [ (this.props.message.sender == this.props.from) ? styles.message_bubble_to_img : styles.message_bubble_img ] }>

              <Image source={{ uri: `http://localhost:1337/${this.props.message.message}` }} style={ styles.image } />

            </View>

          : (this.props.message.type == 'voice_note')

          ? <View style={ [ (this.props.message.sender == this.props.from) ? styles.message_bubble_to : styles.message_bubble, styles.voice_note_bubble ] }>

                {
                  this.state.is_playing
                  ? <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.play_sound(`http://localhost:1337/${this.props.message.message}`) }>
                      <Icon name="ios-pause" type="Ionicons" style={ styles.play_sound } />
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                  : <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.play_sound(`http://localhost:1337/${this.props.message.message}`) }>
                      <Icon name="ios-play" type="Ionicons" style={ styles.play_sound } />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }

              <Text style={ styles.voice_note_time }> { moment(this.state.timer).format('mm:ss') } </Text>

            </View>

          : <View style={ [ (this.props.message.sender == this.props.from) ? styles.message_bubble_to : styles.message_bubble ] }>

             <Text style={ [ (this.props.message.sender == this.props.from) ? styles.message_bubble_txt_to : styles.message_bubble_txt ] }>{ this.props.message.message }</Text>

           </View>

        }

      </View>

      <View style={ [ styles.message_date_container, (this.props.message.sender == this.props.from) ? { justifyContent: 'flex-start' } : { justifyContent: 'flex-end' } ] }>

        <Text style={ styles.message_date }>{ moment(this.props.message.date).format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A') }</Text>

      </View>


  </View>

)

}

}
```

Here is my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>labayh</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Labayh</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>OPENTOK_API_KEY</key>
    <string>46232102</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Camera Usage</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to access you microphone.</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to save photos to your photo gallery</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like access to your photo gallery</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>DINNextLTArabic-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto_medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Roboto.ttf</string>
        <string>rubicon-icon-font.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you use for images and sounds are all located on your computer, and you are referring to them using localhost:1337/... 
This will obviously not work on a physical device, those files will need to be added to the iOS and/or Android assets and you need to reference them differently using require('')

More information on using static resources can be found [in the official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images).

Comment: Just realized that .. what a stupid mistake .. ‍♂️ you're absolutely right ..